# reading large xml file: go encoding/xml is twice as slow as python lxml

Tags: python, xml, go

I was considering to adapt go for my future projects for performance reason but there is a big surprise: go's running time is 13.974427s while pythons elapsed time is just 6.593028783798218s
Less then a half!

The XML file size is over 300 MB.
Here is the pythons's code:

```
from lxml import objectify
import time

most = time.time()

root = objectify.parse(open(r"c:\temp\myfile.xml", 'rb')).getroot()

if hasattr(root, 'BaseData'):
    if hasattr(root.BaseData, 'SzTTs'):
        total_records = 0
        for sztt in root.BaseData.SzTTs.sztt:
            total_records += 1
print("total_records", total_records)
print("Time elapsed: ", time.time()-most)
```

and here is the simplified go code:

```
package main

// An example streaming XML parser.

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "time"
)

var inputFile = "c:\\temp\\myfile.xml"

type SzTTs struct {
    Sztt []sztt
}

type sztt struct {
}

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open(inputFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    d := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
    total1 := 0
    total2 := 0
    start := time.Now()
    for {
        // Read tokens from the XML document in a stream.
        t, err := d.Token()
        // If we are at the end of the file, we are done
        if t == nil || err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("The end")
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error decoding token: %s", err)
        }

        // Inspect the type of the token just read.
        switch se := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:

            if se.Name.Local == "SzTTs" {
                var p SzTTs
                // decode a whole chunk of following XML into the
                // variable p which is a Page (se above)
                if err = d.DecodeElement(&p, &se); err != nil {
                    log.Fatalf("Error decoding item: %s", err)
                }
                for i := range p.Sztt {
                    total1 = i
                }
            }
        default:
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("Total sztt: %d \n", total1)
    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time %s", time.Since(start))
}
```

Why is this big difference?

Comment: You could start by buffering your file io. For the rest: Different languages and different libraries.

Comment: xml.NewDecoder already creates bufio.Reader. So the file reading is buffered.

Comment: Go isn't necessarily faster than other languages. If you want to adopt Go you are probably looking for other features rather than only execution time. Features like: channels, goroutines, type safety, and so on.

Comment: This is a comparison between an optimized C library (`lxml`, which the Python module is a thin wrapper of) and a native Go library. `lxml` is written in "cython" which is essentially a Pythonish DSL over C. It should be possible to get similar performance by wrapping a C XML parser with CGO or some such

Answer (score 5):

To expand upon my comment - *this is expected*.

Go's `encoding/xml` is written in pure Go, whereas `lxml` is written in C, essentially. It's using Cython, which generates C code from a Python-like DSL.

2x is not a huge performance difference IMHO, but if every last drop of performance matters to you, consider using another Go package - one that wraps an optimized C implementation.

For example, libxml (one of the most popular C implementations) has several wrappers:

- https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri
- https://github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2

I expect these will be much faster than `encoding/xml`.

---

Edid (2019-07-22): This question inspired me to [write more about streaming XML performance in Go](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/faster-xml-stream-processing-in-go/), and [a new wrapper for the libxml SAX interface](https://github.com/eliben/gosax).